# How to fix error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I still have no idea how to fetch data from my action.

Here is the action:

```
import myConstant from './constatnts'
...
export const fetchData = {
  isLoading,
  isSuccess,
  ...
};

const isLoading = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: myConstant.FETCH_LOADING,
    payload: LoadingApi()
  });
}
```

And also tried to use ES5:

```
function isSuccess() {
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({
      type: myConstant.FETCH_DATA
      payload: fetchDataApi()
    });
  };
}
```

and I have an error to get data to Redux in Component:

```
import {fetchData} from './myData'

componentWillMount() {
  fetchData.isSuccess; // or fetchData.isLoading
}
```

I have got the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
>   no-unused-expressions

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your action using dispatch keywoard. If you want to use dispatch keyword from a react component then you need to wrap your Component with `connect()` function from `react-redux` package.

Next you will need to define at least `mapStateToProps` function to get data (EDIT: you do not need to include mapStateToProps :) include it only when you want to get some data back to your component), which you saved into the store by your reducer, from your redux store into your component as props.

So your code should looks like following:

```
import {fetchData} from './myData'
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class YourComp extends Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchData.isSuccess());
  }
  ...
}

// this will push data from the store to your props
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  yourData: state.reducer.data
});

// besides other things, this line will push dispatch function callback into your component's props
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComp);
```

Comment: Thanks, it help's me to understand!

Answer (score 0):

you should be carefull with the syntax---

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>({
   
})
 
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    addExpenseHandler : (expenseItemData) => dispatch(addExpenseItemData(expenseItemData))
})
```